# Lattices in a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

{\alpha belongs to K such that \alpha M \subset M}. Is it a Z lattice where K is a number field of degree n and M=Z a_1+...+Z a_n , {a_1,...a_n} is a basis of K over Q.

---

My (=JL) interpretation of what the question is asking:

---

Assume that $K$ is a number field, $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=n$, $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n\}$ is a basis of $K$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$, and $M=\Bbb{Z}a_1+\Bbb{Z}a_2+\cdots+\Bbb{Z}a_n$ is the given free abelian group. Define
$$
\Lambda=\{\alpha\in K\mid \alpha M\subseteq M\}.
$$
Is $\Lambda$ a lattice in $K$?

Comment: Jun Jo Li, it seems to me that you are somewhat unfamiliar about adding TeX to your question, and that you are not fluent in mathematical English. That's very much ok! I made an attempt to rewrite and interpret your question. Please comment here, if I made any errors, or somehow mispresented your intention.

Comment: And as a hint to your question: Can you show that if $z\in K$, then there exists an integer $m$ (depending on $z$) that $(mz)\in \Lambda$?